# Dell Latitude 5400 Webcam Blurry Hardware Issue

Tags: webcam, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude 5400 with an integrated webcam.  One day upon starting up the image was blurry, and I can't find any place where I can change the focus of the integrated webcam.  This isn't a software issue as the same blurred image persists across any video-based software, and the clear plastic covering the camera has been cleaned multiple times.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, use the [Dell SupportAssist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZHHF89U2ts) application and see if that resolves the webcam issue.

[image: Dell SupportAssist for Webcam]

If not, download the [Dell Latitude 5400 Service Manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/latitude-14-5400-laptop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf). On p. 96, there are directions for removing and replacing the webcam, though perhaps "percussive maintenance" (a *gentle* tap or two on the side of the camera) can loosen up a stuck part.

BTW, before that first cup of coffee, I'm also a bit blurry.